# passing a string to javascript function and convert it

Tags: javascript

```
var str1 = document.getElementById('string').value;

var str = str1.toUpperCase();

function correctstring() {
    for (var i=0;i < str.length ; i++) {
        if(str[i]==='H'){str[i]='R';}
            else if(str[i]==='V'){str[i]='L';}
            else if (str[i] === 'G'){ str[i]='F'; }
            else  {atert('the string has a wrong input, Please enter the right chars for english(R,L,F) for swedish (H,V,G)');
       }
    }
}

correctstring();
```

Comment: it is not working .. anybody can help me?

Comment: How will you know it works? I believe there's a typo there: `atert` vs `alert`.

Comment: `str[i]='R'`; strings in JavaScript are *immutable*, you cannot assign via index or modify them in situ in any way. You need to construct a new string (or assign to an array then join)

Comment: ooooh
it is typing wrong .. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

String isn't considered array in JS, just cast it as array and then cast i back:

```
st = str1.split("");
//Your code
str1 = st.join("")
```

**Don't forget to change *str1* to *st* in your loop**

Comment: and as @Tamas Rev said: you should fix "atert" to "alert"